# How to solve this step to get this

Tags: trigonometry

$\sqrt{2A^2(1+\cos \theta)} $

to

$\sqrt{4A^2\cos^2 \dfrac {\theta} {2}}$  (Here, divided by $2$ is only under $\theta$)

I have solved till : $\dfrac {2A\sqrt{1+\cos\theta}}{2}$ (divided by $2$ is whole under $1 + \cos \theta$)

Comment: $\cos(\theta)=\cos (2\theta/2)=2\cos^2(\theta/2)-1\implies 2A^2(1+\cos(\theta))=4A\cos^2(\theta/2) $

Comment: @Koro Thanks. How did you solve the 3rd step ?

Comment: Your "till" result is wrong.

Comment: @Koro: I think you're missing a factor of $A$ when you went to the third step (it should be $4A^2)$.

Comment: @bjcolby15: Ooops, I missed that. You are right. It should be $4A^2$ instead of $4A$ in last step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Using the trigonometric identity (a variation of the half-angle formula) $$\cos^2 \dfrac {\theta}{2} = \dfrac {1 + \cos \theta}{2}$$ rewrite this expression in terms of $1 + \cos \theta$ only, and the answer will be immediate.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.